# Question asker has changed which answer is accepted but new answer is less accurate than my own

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

A while ago, a user asked a question about what the correct mime type was for WOFF files in **nginx**: [Proper MIME type for .woff2 fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28235550/633056). I answered this question very accurately (in my opinion).

I have recently realised that the user has un-marked my answer and awarded the answer to another answer. However, this other answer specifically answers the question regarding **IIS**.

I do not feel that this is just but I am not sure if that is regarded a reasonable here, on Stack Overflow. I have reached out to the user but they have not responded.

What should I do?

Comment: Well, either improve your answer more, or just move on.

Comment: The accepted answer tells other users which answer the OP found most useful, that's all. Even if that's not the best answer (which isn't always the case), that's the one that helped them.

Comment: There is nothing you can do.  The check mark is there for the OP to give to whoever he wants.  Go forth and continue to come up with good answer not caring if the OP chooses yours.

Comment: The checkmark indicates what OP found most useful. *Votes* indicate what the community-at-large find most useful. It is not uncommon (by far) to see a zero- or even negatively-voted answer "here is some code" getting the Accept, while another longer answer explaining a topic in depth gets all the votes.

Comment: Cannot understand the downvotes on this meta question. It's "what should I do" and not "I want that tick mark back".

Comment: @NathanOliver There is nothing you can do is not completely true. You could comment on the other answer and point out the inaccuracies, hoping that the OP sees them and changes his mind again. Although I agree that this is about what one can do.

Comment: @Trilarion Yeah, the downvotes seem a little harsh. Isn't this kind of question what Meta is for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at that question, it seems your primary answer has become outdated.  The comments later say

> the spec document has revoked the endorsement of `application/font-woff2`

That would seem to justify changing the checkmark.

Now, it appears that you mentioned the new correct MIME type later in your answer, but that doesn't override your initial claim (which is phrased authoritatively).

Personally I think that fantastory deserves the credit for having been first to give and explain the new value.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the different perspective.